# LINQPad [extension] methods

Tags: c#, windows, linqpad

Does anyone have a complete list of LINQPad extension methods and methods, such as

```cs
.Dump()

SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because LINQPad is an ever-changing tool, having a solid and concrete and *final* answer on this question will have a very short life. I propose to close it as off-topic to avoid promoting similar questions for other tools.

Comment: Not that I have anything to say about voting, but I certainly disagree with closing this answer. First, just look at the upvotes for the question, then look at the upvotes for the first two comments. Second, how can the answers from Joseph be less than a final answer; he wrote the thing. Finally, other applications use Stackoverflow for their documentation. I use LinqPad for development all the time, prototyping C# and Linq queries, running SQL, and doing Quick DBA tasks, and dozens of other things. So, at least for me, answers are definitely on topic.

Comment: Re closing: I've added more than one answer to older questions on C# to provide a more modern technique that has been introduced to the language since the question was answered. IMO we should expect that the knowledgebase this site represents is modified and updated as technology moves on. The range of topics where future updates can compromise or nullify answers given at a particular point in time is quite broad: if we closed all questions where this might happen, Stack Overflow would be a much poorer resource! Here, a complete list may become a partial list which is better than no list!

Comment: This should not be discussed here. Bring it to [meta].

Comment: @Samuel Liew:  I don't agree to the closing of this question: If you're closing this question, then you need to close all other questions referring to Microsoft Products, such as Visual Studio, SQL Server, Azure, ... and remove their tags as well - because that is also referring to Software.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

LINQPad defines two extension methods (in LINQPad.Extensions), namely `Dump()` and `Disassemble()`. `Dump()` writes to the output window using LINQPad's output formatter and is overloaded to let you specify a heading:

```cs
typeof (int).Assembly.Dump ();
typeof (int).Assembly.Dump ("mscorlib");
```

You can also specify a maximum recursion depth to override the default of 5 levels:

```cs
typeof (int).Assembly.Dump (1);              // Dump just one level deep
typeof (int).Assembly.Dump (7);              // Dump 7 levels deep
typeof (int).Assembly.Dump ("mscorlib", 7);  // Dump 7 levels deep with heading
```

Disassemble() disassembles any method to `IL`, returning the output in a string:

```cs
typeof (Uri).GetMethod ("GetHashCode").Disassemble().Dump();
```

In addition to those two extension methods, there are some useful static methods in LINQPad.Util. These are documented in autocompletion, and include:

- **Cmd** - executes a shell command or external program
- **CreateXhtmlWriter** - creates a text writer that uses LINQPad's Dump() formatter
- **SqlOutputWriter** - returns the text writer that writes to the SQL output window
- **GetMyQueries**, **GetSamples** - returns a collection of objects representing your saved queries / samples (for an example, execute a search using Edit | Search All)
- **Highlight** - wraps an object so that it will highlight in yellow when Dumped
- **HorizontalRun** - lets you Dump a series of objects on the same line

LINQPad also provides the HyperLinq class. This has two purposes: the first is to display ordinary hyperlinks:

```cs
new Hyperlinq ("www.linqpad.net").Dump();
new Hyperlinq ("www.linqpad.net", "Web site").Dump();
new Hyperlinq ("mailto:user@domain.example", "Email").Dump();
```

You can combine this with `Util.HorizontalRun`:

```cs
Util.HorizontalRun (true,
  "Check out",
   new Hyperlinq ("http://stackoverflow.com", "this site"),
  "for answers to programming questions.").Dump();
```

Result:

> **Check out [this site](http://stackoverflow.com) for answers to programming questions.**

The second purpose of HyperLinq is to dynamically build queries:

```cs
// Dynamically build simple expression:
new Hyperlinq (QueryLanguage.Expression, "123 * 234").Dump();

// Dynamically build query:
new Hyperlinq (QueryLanguage.Expression, @"from c in Customers
where c.Name.Length > 3
select c.Name", "Click to run!").Dump();
```

You can also write your own extension methods in LINQPad. Go to 'My Queries' and click the query called 'My Extensions'. Any types/methods that define here are accessible to all queries:

```cs
void Main()
{
  "hello".Pascal().Dump();
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static string Pascal (this string s)
  {
    return char.ToLower (s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
  }
}
```

In 4.46(.02) [new classes and methods have been introduced](http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx):

- DumpContainer (class)
- OnDemand (extension method)
- Util.ProgressBar (class)

Additionally, the Hyperlinq class now supports an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate that will be called when you click the link, allowing you to react to it in code and not just link to external webpages.

`DumpContainer` is a class that adds a block into the output window that can have its contents replaced.

**NOTE!** Remember to `.Dump()` the `DumpContainer` itself in the appropriate spot.

To use:

```cs
var dc = new DumpContainer();
dc.Content = "Test";
// further down in the code
dc.Content = "Another test";
```

`OnDemand` is an extension method that will not output the contents of its parameter to the output window, but instead add a clickable link, that when clicked will replace the link with the `.Dump()`ed contents of the parameter. This is great for sometimes-needed data structures that is costly or takes up a lot of space.

**NOTE!** Remember to `.Dump()` the results of calling `OnDemand` in the appropriate spot.

To use it:

```cs
Customers.OnDemand("Customers").Dump(); // description is optional
```

`Util.ProgressBar` is a class that can show a graphical progressbar inside the output window, that can be changed as the code moves on.

**NOTE!** Remember to `.Dump()` the Util.ProgressBar object in the appropriate spot.

To use it:

```cs
var pb = new Util.ProgressBar("Analyzing data");
pb.Dump();
for (int index = 0; index <= 100; index++)
{
    pb.Percent = index;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: Nothing better than an answer from the author himself!

Comment: Joe, I actually wanted to prototype some graphics work as well and then wanted to dump out a bitmap; it'd be great with a Show method for this kind of work where you want some visualization, working on Graphics, Image, etc. Possibly providing neat visualizations for some other types down the road.

Comment: ...Actually, as long as you can send graphics to the output panel, we can build extensions for the rest ourselves.

Comment: The 4.26 beta lets you inject XHTML into the output stream, by calling Util.RawHtml. Go to www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx (or wait a few days for RTM).

Comment: Joe, is it also possible to access current data context or sql connection from within a 'C# Statement(s)' query ?

(What i want to achieve is to execute plain sql (or t-sql) from c#.)

Comment: How can I Prevent adding new line after `Dump` method? For example I want to make `ProgressBar` vs `DumpContainer` (that will show text percents) in one line

Comment: Alex - to get >1 thing onto a line, use Util.HorizontalRun

Comment: `.ToClipBoard()` would be a nice addition.  Perform just like .Dump() but goes to Copy.

Comment: Hi Joe, where is THE location you put all the manuals together?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I absolutely love using Linqpad, but paying almost 100 bucks and having to scour stackoverflow and the net for documentation is as tedious as it is time consuming.

Comment: All of these features and more are very handily showcased in the "LINQPad Tutorial & Reference" samples category from within LINQPad itself.

Comment: I just bought a premium license. Why I did not hear about all of this before .

Answer (score 157):

## LinqPad extension methods  -   Part 1 of 2

<sup>[Go to part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743368/1016343)</sup>

---

Besides the well-known `myQuery.Dump("Query result:")`, another feature to mention is the `Util` class: It contains many quite handy methods (some of them I've mentioned, but there are a lot more).

Also interesting is that you can **modify the way `Dump()` works**.

Finally I'll show you how you can **make changes permanent** (i.e. *insert, update, delete* LINQ queries) using `SubmitChanges()` or `SaveChanges()` as well as how you can access the internal connection object of LinqPad.

To round it up, I'll show you how you can create simple **2d graphic** inside of LinqPad (drawing *lines, bitmaps* or *functions*).

So, here's a collection of **built in LinqPad features** (from my own experience with the tool):

---

### .Dump()

*(parameters available in LinqPad v5.03.08 and above)*

The `.Dump()` extension method consumes and prints (almost) everything.

But did you know there are a couple of parameters available?
Take a look at this code snippet:

```cs
var obj=new { a="Hello", b=5, c="World", d=new { y=5, z=10 } };
obj.Dump(description: "1st example", depth: 5, toDataGrid: false, exclude: "b,d");
obj.Dump("2nd example", exclude: "a,c");
obj.Dump("2nd example", exclude: "+b,d"); // new in V5.06.06 beta
```

The *1st example* prints only variables `a` and `c` and hides `b` and `d`, the *2nd example* does the opposite (note that it specifies only 2 of the available parameters). The variables`y` and `z` cannot be hidden individually, because they are not at the top level.

The following parameters are available (**all are optional**):

- `description` [string] - provides a description for the object to dump
- `depth` [int?] - limits how deep the objects are recursively inspected
- `toDataGrid` [bool] - if true, the output is formatted as a datagrid rather than as RichText
- `exclude` [string] - if you provide a comma-separated list of variables, they will be excluded from the output (in the example "a,c": `b` and `d` are shown, `a` and `c` are hidden)
- `exclude` [string] with "+" prefix - the prefix inverts the logic of the exclude parameter. This means, if you provide a comma-separated list of variables, all except the ones specified are hidden (in the example "+b,d": `b` and `d` are shown, all others hidden)
- store included and excluded properties in a variable (new since LinqPad V5.09.04): 
  `var x=Util.ToExpando(obj, "a, c", "b, d"); x.Dump();` 
   The first string contains a list of properties to include, the second string a list to exclude
- expand on click: If you use `.OnDemand("click me").Dump();` instead of `.Dump()`, it will display a link you can click on to expand. Useful if you want to inspect values, e.g. `Util.OnDemand("Customer-ID: " + customerObject.ID.ToString(), ()=>customerObject, false).Dump();` to always show the ID per default but reveal the details of `customerObject` only if you're interested in.

More advanced topics about Dump can be found 
[here (Customizing Dump)](http://www.linqpad.net/CustomizingDump.aspx) and [there (Extensions Part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743368/1016343).

---

### Util.WriteCsv

(**new:** available since [LinqPad version v4.45.05 (beta)](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx))

```cs
Util.WriteCsv (Customers, @"c:\temp\customers.csv");
```

This will write the content of the table `Customers` to the CSV file `c:\temp\customers.csv`. You can also find a nice example how to use `Util.WriteCsv` and then display the CSV data in Linqpad's result window [here](http://www.developertipoftheday.com/2012/10/read-csv-in-linqpad.html).

**Hints:**

- To get/create a CSV file which is in the same directory as the query, you can use:
  `var csvFile=Util.CurrentQueryPath.Replace(".linq", ".csv");`
- If the table is large, use `ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;` before you write the CSV to avoid caching it in memory.
- If you want to output a table in **XML format** rather than as comma-separated file, you can do it like:

  ```cs
    var xmlFile=Util.CurrentQueryPath.Replace(".linq", ".xml");
    var xml = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
    var query =
      from e in xml.Elements()
      where e.Attribute("attr1").Value == "a"
      select e;
    query.Dump();
  ```

This example returns all elements having the attribute `attr1` which contains the value `"a"` from an XML file which has the same name as the query and is contained in the same path. Check out [this](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/250-linqpad-xml-as-a-data-source/) link for more code samples.

---

### Util.GetPassword

```cs
var pwd = Util.GetPassword("UserXY");
```

This will retrieve the password from LinqPad's built in password manager. To create & change the password, open the **"Password manager" menu item** in the **"File" menu** of LinqPad. If there is no password saved when you run the C# code, a password dialog will open up asking you for the password and you have the choice to create and save it on the fly by checking the *save password* checkbox (in the example, the password for "UserXY" would be saved, and later on you can find this entry in the **Password manager**).

Advantages are that you can store the password in the LinqScripts you create securely, separately and encrypted in Windows' user profile (it is stored in `%localappdata%\LINQPad\Passwords` as a file). LinqPad uses Windows DPAPI to protect the password.

Also, the password is stored centrally, so if you need to change it, you can do it in the menu and it immediately applies to all scripts you've created.

**Notes:**

- If you don't want to save the password and just bring up a password dialog, you can use the 2nd parameter as follows:
  `var pwd = Util.GetPassword("UserXY", true);`
  This will uncheck the *save password* checkbox in the password dialog (however, the user is still able to check it and choose to save anyway).
- If you require the password to be stored in a `SecureString`, you can use this helper function (n.b.: to get the extension method `.ToSecureString()` used, please follow [this link at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016279/1016343) - it also allows you to convert it back if needed): 
  `System.Security.SecureString GetPasswordSecure(string Name, bool noDefaultSave=true)`
  `{`
       `return Util.GetPassword(Name, noDefaultSave)`[`.ToSecureString();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016279/1016343)
  `}`

---

### Util.Cmd

This method works like a command processor. You can invoke all commands you know from the Windows console.

**Example 1 - dir:**

```cs
Util.Cmd(@"dir C:\");
```

This will output the result of the directory without the need to `.Dump` it. Storing it in a variable has the advantage that you can use further Linq queries on it. For example:

```cs
var path=@"C:\windows\system32"; 
var dirSwitch="/s/b";
var x=Util.Cmd(String.Format(@"dir ""{0}"" {1}", path, dirSwitch), true);
var q=from d in x 
        where d.Contains(".exe") || d.Contains(".dll")              
        orderby d
    select d;
q.Dump();
```

This will dump all files with file extensions ".exe" or ".dll" contained in `C:\windows\system32`. The `/s` switch is used to recurse all subdirectories and `/b` is used for bare output format. Note that the second parameter of the Cmd method is specified to suppress the console output in order to show only the filtered result using the Dump method.

You can see that this is more flexible than the wildcards you have with `dir` since you can use the full flexibility of Linq's query engine.

**Example 2 - text editor:**

You can open a file in Notepad like this:

```cs
var filePath=@"C:\HelloWorld.txt";
Util.Cmd(@"%systemroot%\system32\notepad.exe", filePath);
```

---

### Util.Image

Displays images from an URL. Example:

```cs
var url = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=s:Uf9a&chs=350x140&chl=January|February|March|April";
Util.Image(url).Dump();
```

---

### Util.ProgressBar, Util.Progress

Using `Util.ProgressBar` allows you to display a progress bar. You can use the following helper class:

```cs
public class ProgressBar
{
    Util.ProgressBar prog;
    
    public ProgressBar() 
    { 
        Init("Processing"); 
    }
    
    private void Init(string msg)
    {
        prog = new Util.ProgressBar (msg).Dump();
        prog.Percent=0;
    }

    public void Update(int percent)
    {
        Update(percent, null);
    }   
    
    public void Update(int percent, string msg)
    {
        prog.Percent=percent;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
        {
            if (percent>99) prog.Caption="Done.";
        }
        else
        {
            prog.Caption=msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply use it as the following example shows:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var pb1= new ProgressBar();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    pb1.Update(50, "Doing something"); Thread.Sleep(550);
    pb1.Update(100); Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

You can alternatively use `Util.Progress` to update LinqPads integrated progress bar, for example:

```cs
Util.Progress = 25; // 25 percent complete
```

The difference is that it will not display in the results window, and you can't assign a message to it.

---

### Util.RawHtml

Displays HTML in the output window. Example:

```cs
Util.RawHtml (new XElement ("h1", "This is a big heading")).Dump();
```

---

### Hyperlinq, Util.HorizontalRun

You can use this example function

```cs
public void ShowUrl(string strURL, string Title)
{
    Action showURL = delegate() { Process.Start("iexplore.exe", strURL); };
    var url = new Hyperlinq(showURL, "this link", true);
    Util.HorizontalRun (true, "Click ", url, " for details.").Dump(Title);
}
```

to show hyperlinks in the result window - or any actions like opening your favourite editor.
**Usage:**

```cs
ShowUrl("http://stackoverflow.com", "Check out StackOverflow");
```

**Note** that this function always works, while `new Hyperlinq ("http://myURL", "Web site").Dump();` does not work for some kind of URLs (especially, if you have to pass port names like ":1234" as part of the URL).

---

### Util.ReadLine

Reads input from the console. Example:

```cs
int age = Util.ReadLine<int> ("Enter your age");
```

As a synonym for `Util.ReadLine<string>()`, you can use `Console.ReadLine()` as well.

But there is more! You can create a **simple JSON parser** with the following snippet - quite useful, for example if you want to parse and test a JSON string on the fly. *Save the following snippet as **JSONAnalyzer.linq** using a text editor* and then open it in LinqPad (this is to add the references easily on the fly):

```cs
<Query Kind="Program">
    <Reference>&lt;RuntimeDirectory&gt;\System.Web.Extensions.dll</Reference>
    <Namespace>System.Web.Script.Serialization</Namespace>
</Query>

void Main()
{
    var jsonData=Util.ReadLine<string>("Enter JSON string:");
    var jsonAsObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(jsonData);
    jsonAsObject.Dump("Deserialized JSON");
}
```

Now you can run it and simply paste a JSON string from the clipboard into the console - it will use the `Dump` function to display it as an object nicely - and you also get the error messages of the parser on the screen to fix issues. Very useful for debugging AJAX.

[image: JSON]

---

### Util.ClearResults

If you need to clear the results window inside your script, use:

```cs
Util.ClearResults();
```

Either use it at the top of your script, or - if you're running multiple queries in a script - you should wait for user input before blanking the screen (e.g. by preceding it with `Util.ReadLine`).

---

### Custom .Dump() - ICustomMemberProvider

Also interesting is, that you can change the output of the `.Dump()` method. Simply implement the interface `ICustomMemberProvider`, e.g.

```cs
public class test : ICustomMemberProvider 
{

      IEnumerable<string> ICustomMemberProvider.GetNames() {
        return new List<string>{"Hint", "constMember1", "constMember2", "myprop"};
      }
      
      IEnumerable<Type> ICustomMemberProvider.GetTypes() 
      {
        return new List<Type>{typeof(string), typeof(string[]), 
            typeof(string), typeof(string)};
      }
      
      IEnumerable<object> ICustomMemberProvider.GetValues() 
      {
        return new List<object>{
        "This class contains custom properties for .Dump()", 
        new string[]{"A", "B", "C"}, "blabla", abc};
      }

      public string abc = "Hello1"; // abc is shown as "myprop"
      public string xyz = "Hello2"; // xyz is entirely hidden
}
```

If you create an instance of this class, like

```cs
var obj1 = new test();
obj1.Dump("Test");
```

then it will output only `Hint`, `constMember1`, `constMember2`, and `myprop`, but not property `xyz`:

[image: Linqpad dump]

---

### Displaying a MessageBox or InputBox in LinqPad

If you need to display a messagebox, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22557566/1016343) how to do it.

For example, you can display an InputBox by using the following code

```cs
void Main()
{
    string inputValue="John Doe"; 
    inputValue=Interaction.InputBox("Enter user name", "Query", inputValue);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputValue)) // not cancelled and value entered
    {
        inputValue.Dump("You have entered;"); // either display it in results window
        Interaction.MsgBox(inputValue, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Result"); // or as MsgBox
    }
}
```

(don't forget to press F4 and add Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and its namespaces to make this work)

---

### Util.Run

(**new:** available since [LinqPad version v4.52.1 (beta)](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx))

Allows you to run another LINQPad script from within your script or within your own .NET program or Windows service (by referencing the LINQPad4-AnyCPU version of `LINQPad.exe`). It executes the script just as the command line tool `lprun.exe` would do it.

**Examples:**

```cs
const string path=@"C:\myScripts\LinqPad\";
var dummy=new LINQPad.QueryResultFormat(); // needed to call Util.Run
Util.Run(path+"foo.linq", dummy);
```

This example runs the script `foo.linq`, which contains the following sample code:

```cs
void Main(string[] args)
{
    #if CMD
       "I'm been called from lprun! (command line)".Dump();
    #else
       "I'm running in the LINQPad GUI!".Dump();
       args = new[] { "testhost", "test@foo.com", "test@foo.com", "Test Subject" };
    #endif
    args.Dump("Args");
}
```

It allows you to check if the script was run from inside the LinqPad GUI or via `lprun.exe` or with `Util.Run`.

**Note:** The following variants of invocation might be helpful:

```cs
Util.Run(path+"foo.linq", dummy).Dump(); // obviously dumps the script output!
Util.Run(path+"foo.linq", dummy).Save(path+"foo.log"); // writes output into log
Util.Run(path+"foo.linq", dummy).SaveAsync(path+"foo1.log");     // async output log
```

---

### SubmitChanges() - Linq To SQL

If you're using **LinqToSQL**, you might want to make changes permanent (for *insert/update/delete* operations).
Since the database context is implicitly made by LinqPad, you need to call  `SubmitChanges()` after each change as shown below.

**Examples for *(LinqPad-)Northwind* database:**

**Insert**

```cs
var newP = new Products() { ProductID=pID, CategoryID=cID, 
            ProductName="Salmon#"+pID.ToString() };
Products.InsertOnSubmit(newP);
SubmitChanges();
```

**Update**

```cs
var prod=(from p in Products
            where p.ProductName.Contains("Salmon")
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
prod.ProductName="Trout#"+prod.ProductID.ToString();
SubmitChanges();
```

**Delete**

```cs
var itemsToDelete=Products.Where(p=> p.ProductName.Contains("Salmon") ||
    p.ProductName.Contains("Trout"));
foreach(var item in itemsToDelete) { Products.DeleteOnSubmit(item); }
SubmitChanges();
```

**Note:** In order to get valid IDs for the previous examples, you can use:

```cs
var cID = (from c in Categories 
            where c.CategoryName.Contains("Seafood") 
            select c).FirstOrDefault().CategoryID;

var pID = Products.Count()+1;
```

before you invoke them.

---

### SaveChanges() - Entity Framework

If you're using **Entity Framework**, you might want to make changes permanent as well (for *insert/update/delete* operations).
Since the database context is implicitly made by LinqPad, you need to call  `SaveChanges()` after each change as shown below.

The examples are basically the same as before for **LinqToSQL**, but you need to use `SaveChanges()` instead, and for inserting and deleting the methods have changed as well.

**Insert**

```cs
var newP = new Products() { ProductID=pID, CategoryID=cID, 
            ProductName="Salmon#"+pID.ToString() };
Products.Add(newP);
SaveChanges();
```

**Update**

```cs
var prod=(from p in Products
            where p.ProductName.Contains("Salmon")
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
prod.ProductName="Trout#"+prod.ProductID.ToString();
SaveChanges();
```

**Delete**

```cs
var itemsToDelete=Products.Where(p=> p.ProductName.Contains("Salmon") ||
    p.ProductName.Contains("Trout"));
foreach(var item in itemsToDelete) { Products.Remove(item); }
SaveChanges();
```

**Note:** In order to get valid IDs for the previous examples, you can use:

```cs
var cID = (from c in Categories 
            where c.CategoryName.Contains("Seafood") 
            select c).FirstOrDefault().CategoryID;

var pID = Products.Count()+1;
```

before you invoke them.

If you need to have transactions, take a look at this post: [How to nest transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71481621/1016343).

---

### this - database context

In **LinqPad**, the **database context** is applied automatically by using the combobox at the top and picking the right database for your query.
But sometimes, it is useful to reference it explicitly, for example if you copy some code from your project out of **Visual Studio**, and paste it into LinqPad.

Your code snippet taken from the Visual Studio project very likely looks like this:

```cs
var prod=(from p in dc.Products
            where p.ProductName.Contains("Salmon")
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
prod.ProductName="Trout#"+prod.ProductID.ToString();
dc.SaveChanges();
```

Now what to do with `dc`? Of course, you could remove each occurrence of `dc.` in your query, but it is much easier.
Just add it to the top of your snippet like so:

```cs
UserQuery dc { get => this; }
void Main()
{
    var prod=(from p in dc.Products
                where p.ProductName.Contains("Salmon")
                select p).FirstOrDefault();
    prod.ProductName="Trout#"+prod.ProductID.ToString();
    dc.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

and the code will work instantly!

---

### this.Connection

**Using LinqPad with OleDb, converting a datatable to Linq object, SQL queries in Linq**

The following code snippet helps you to use LinqPad with OleDb. Add `System.Data.OleDb` from the `System.Data` assembly to the query properties, then paste the following code into `Main()`:

```cs
var connStr="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"+this.Connection.ConnectionString; 

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
conn.Open();

string sql = @"SELECT * from Customers";
OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adpt.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn); 
adpt.Fill(myDS);

myDS.Dump();
```

Now add a SqlServer connection to LinqPad and add the Northwind database in order to run this example.

**N.B.:** If you just want to get the database and server of the currently selected connection, you can use this code snippet:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var dc=this;
    var tgtSrv=dc.Connection.DataSource;
    var tgtDb=dc.Connection.ConnectionString.Split(';').Select(s=>s.Trim())
        .Where(x=>x.StartsWith("initial catalog", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .ToArray()[0].Split('=')[1];
    tgtSrv.Dump();
    tgtDb.Dump();
}
```

You can even convert `myDS` into **Linq,** the answers to the following question show how to do it: [Nice examples of using .NET 4 dynamic keyword with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4117713/1016343)

One more example: Suppose your DBA gives you a SQL query and you want to analyze the results in LinqPad - of course in Linq, not in SQL. You can do the following:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var dc=this;
    
    // do the SQL query
    var cmd =
        "SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName,"
        +"       Customers.Address, Customers.City"
        +" FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID";
    var results = dc.ExecuteQuery<OrderResult>(cmd);
    
    // just get the cities back, ordered ascending
    results.Select(x=>x.City).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).Dump();
}

class OrderResult
{   // put here all the fields you're returning from the SELECT
    public dynamic OrderID=null; 
    public dynamic CustomerID=null;
    public dynamic CompanyName=null;
    public dynamic Address=null;
    public dynamic City=null;
}
```

In this example the DBA's SELECT query is just "thrown into" the command text, and the results are filtered and ordered by City.  
Of course, this is a simplified example, your DBA would probably give you a more complex script, but you're getting the idea: Add a supporting result class which contains all the fields from the SELECT clause, then you can directly use it. 
You can even take the result from a stored procedure this way and use it in Linq. As you can see, in this example I don't care about the data type and use `dynamic` to express it. 
So this is really about rapid programming to be able to analyze data quickly. You shouldn't do this in your real application for various reasons (SQL injection, because you can use EF from the beginning etc).

---

### PanelManager

**Draw graphic in LinqPad, part 1**

To use the examples below, press <kbd>F4</kbd> and add `System.Windows.dll`, `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll`, `PresentationCore.dll` and `PresentationFramework.dll` to your LinqPad program and also add the namespace `System.Windows.Shapes`.

The **1st example** simply draws a line:

```cs
var myLine = new Line();
myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
myLine.X1 = 1; myLine.X2 = 50;
myLine.Y1 = 1; myLine.Y2 = 50;
myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
PanelManager.DisplayWpfElement(myLine, "Graphic");
```

The **2nd example** shows how you can display graphic in LinqPad by using the PanelManager. Normally LinqPad only supports Wpf objects. This example  uses `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` to make a `PictureBox` available (it was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143574/1016343)):

```cs
// needs (F4): System.Windows.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll, 
// WindowsFormsIntegration.dll, PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFramework.dll 
void Main()
{       
    var wfHost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
    wfHost1.Height=175; wfHost1.Width=175; wfHost1.Name="Picturebox1";
    wfHost1.HorizontalAlignment=System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    wfHost1.VerticalAlignment=System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    wfHost1.Child = pBox1;
    pBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(picturebox1_Paint);
    PanelManager.StackWpfElement(wfHost1, "Picture");
} 

public string pathImg
{
    get { return System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\", 
            "Tulips.jpg"); } 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void picturebox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143574/1016343
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(pathImg);
    System.Drawing.Point ulPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, ulPoint.X, ulPoint.Y, 175, 175);
}
```

This will create the following graphic (panel items "Graphic" and "Picture" are added by the examples above):

[image: Showing_Graphic_in_LinqPad]

If you want to **display the images from the Northwind database,** you can do the following:
Change the image file name to "NorthwindPics.jpg", then add the following code at the beginning of the **2nd example's** Main() method:

```cs
var img = (from e in this.Employees select e).FirstOrDefault().Photo.ToArray();
using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(pathImg, FileMode.Create))
{
    const int offset=78;
    fs1.Write(img, offset, img.Length-offset);
    fs1.Close();
}
```

It will read the first record from the Employees table and display the picture.

Check out the following links to find out more: 
[Shapes and basic drawing in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx) 
[LinqPad custom visualizers](http://www.linqpad.net/customvisualizers.aspx)

**Note:** You can achieve the same without the PanelManager as well, as the following example, which I saw [here](https://twitter.com/fekberg/status/704169344578691073/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) shows:

```cs
// using System.Drawing;
using (var image=new Bitmap(100, 100))
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gold, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    gr.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 5, 5, 90, 90);
    gr.Save();
    image.Dump();
}
```

It is using the `.Dump()` command to display it. You can invoke `image.Dump()` multiple times and it will append the image.

---

### Windows Forms

**Draw graphic in LinqPad, part 2**

The following example, inspired by **[this](http://blog.divebomb.org/2012/11/dumping-charts-in-linqpad/)** post, is showing how to implement a function plotter in Linqpad using C#7:

```cs
void Main()
{
    fnPlotter(x1: -1, x2: 1, fn: (double x) => Math.Pow(x, 3)).Dump();
}

public static Bitmap fnPlotter(double x1=-3, double x2=3, double s=0.05, 
                                   double? ymin=null, double? ymax=null, 
                                   Func<double, double> fn = null, bool enable3D=true)
{
    ymin = ymin ?? x1; ymax = ymax ?? x2;
    
    dynamic fArrPair(double p_x1 = -3, double p_x2 = 3, double p_s = 0.01, 
                          Func<double, double> p_fn = null)
    {
        if (p_fn == null) p_fn = ((xf) => { return xf; }); // identity as default
        var xl = new List<double>(); var yl = new List<double>();
        for (var x = p_x1; x <= p_x2; x += p_s)
        {
            double? f = null;
            try { f = p_fn(x); }
            finally
            {
                if (f.HasValue) { xl.Add(x); yl.Add(f.Value); }
            }
        }
        return new { Xs = xl.ToArray(), Ys = yl.ToArray() };
    }

    var chrt = new Chart(); var ca = new ChartArea(); chrt.ChartAreas.Add(ca);
    ca.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = enable3D;
    ca.AxisX.Minimum = x1; ca.AxisX.Maximum = x2;   
    ca.AxisY.Minimum = ymin.Value; ca.AxisY.Maximum = ymax.Value;
        
    var sr = new Series(); chrt.Series.Add(sr);
    sr.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline; sr.Color = Color.Red;
    sr.MarkerColor = Color.Blue; sr.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
    sr.MarkerSize = 2;
                
    var data = fArrPair(x1, x2, s, fn); sr.Points.DataBindXY(data.Xs, data.Ys); 
    var bm = new Bitmap(width: chrt.Width, height: chrt.Height);
    chrt.DrawToBitmap(bm, chrt.Bounds); return bm;
}
```

It is using the capability of LinqPad to display Windows forms in the results panel. 
 [image: Example] 
Add **references (press <kbd>F4</kbd>)**:
 `System.Drawing.dll`, `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll` 
and add all namespaces from these assemblies.

---

**Additional hints / further reading:**

- Want to use LinqPad in **Visual Studio**? Here's [how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199055/1016343).
- Need to have LinqPad as a **"Portable app"**? [Read here](http://www.linqpad.net/PortableDeployment.aspx) how to do that.
- Joe's website for [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is an excellent source. Inside LinqPad, `Help -> What's New` gives you hints about new functions and methods. The [LinqPad Forum](http://forum.linqpad.net/) also contains helpful hints.
- Also helpful: [This](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/) article about Linq(Pad) debugging.
- Use **`lprun.exe`** for **running LINQ queries** in your **batch scripts.** Read [this article](http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx) for more details.
  For example:
  `echo Customers.Take(100) > script.txt` 
  `lprun -lang=e -cxname=CompanyServer.CustomerDb script.txt`
  In this example, the query is a simple LINQ expression. Of course, you can prepare complex queries as well using `-lang=program` to activate the program mode.
- You can write and store extension methods in the **My Queries** tab on the left hand side of LinqPad: The last item of the tree is named **My Extensions**; double click on it to open a file where you can write extensions that are available to all your queries. Put them into the public static class `MyExtensions`, and use the `Main()` method to include tests for your extensions.

---

[Continued here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743368/1016343)

Comment: love the tip about Util.ReadLine<string> ("Enter some json");  Earlier I used to copy it in file and then read from there... I really love this tip. Thanks!

Comment: holy. hell. amongst the best answers ever recorded on here. thank you!!

Comment: Better question perhaps is why this is not all on that native web site.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss - In that case, I would have to sell it to Joe, maybe he'll give me an upgrade of LinqPad for free and then he could publish it on his site ... :-D

Comment: :) He has a LINK to THIS on his site FWIW

Comment: Really?  LOL :-D  Ah yes, I found it: https://www.linqpad.net/Resources.aspx -> General. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 24):

## LinqPad extension methods  -   Part 2 of 2

<sup>[Go to part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006038/1016343)</sup>

---

Reached the **StackOverflow text limit** of 30000 characters in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006038/1016343), but there are still more cool extensions in LinqPad. Some of them I'd like to mention:

---

## Auto-Scrolling and other shortcuts

- **Automatically scroll** to the end of the **Results Window** while a query is running 
  (using `.Dump()` statements): 
  Press **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>** to toggle (turn on or off)
- Multiple entry points: 
  Press **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>** to run `Main1()`, **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>** to run `Main2()`, and so on. 
  **Note** that you still need `void Main()` as main entry point, the methods above are additional (optional) entry points.
- Run xUnit tests: 
  Press **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>** to run **all the xUnit tests** decorated with `[Fact]` or `[Theory]` 
  (as preparation you need to add xUnit support via **Query -> Add xUnit test support** menu)

---

## Environment

This is not a LinqPad extension, but rather a .NET class, but since it is useful, I'll mention it anyway.
You can get a lot of useful information you can use in your scripts such as :

```cs
Environment.UserDomainName.Dump();
Environment.MachineName.Dump();
Environment.UserName.Dump();
Environment.CurrentDirectory.Dump();
Environment.SystemDirectory.Dump();
```

**N.B.** For obtaining `Domain\UserName` I would use    `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
rather than `Environment.UserDomainName+@"\"+Environment.UserName`.

---

## Write your own extensions in LinqPad

**ListTables**

Did you know you can write your own extensions in LinqPad, available in all queries?
Here's how you can do it:
In LinqPad, go to the "My Queries" tab on the left side, scroll down to the end until you see "My Extensions". Double click on it and it will open a special query window named My Extensions. What you write there will become available in all queries.

Now paste the following code into it, then save it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

*My Extensions*

```cs
void Main()
{
    // no code here, but Main() must exist
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This will list the tables of the connected database
    /// </summary>
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<string> ListTables(
                        this System.Data.Linq.DataContext dc, bool dumpIt = true)
    {
       var query = dc.Mapping.GetTables();
       var result = query.Select(t => t.TableName).OrderBy(o => o);
       if (dumpIt) result.Dump();
       return result;
    }
}
```

Joe (the author of LinqPad) kindly provided me this snippet - it shows how you can pass the data context to My Extensions. 
**Note:** For LinqPad 6 or greater, you need to press <kbd>F4</kbd> for query properties and tick "Reference LINQ-to-SQL assemblies" to make it work.

Use this extension the following way: Open a new C# query window in LinqPad (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), then connect to a database of your choice, and type:

*New query*

```cs
void Main()
{
    this.ListTables();
}
```

**Important:** If you're not connected to a database, then the extension is not available and LinqPad will show an error. So, connect to a database first, then type `this.ListTables();`.

Note that IntelliSense will show the summary of the XML comment we typed in My Extensions. Once you run it, you will get a list of the tables of the current database.

---

## Configuration file (appsettings.json) in LinqPad

---

Previously I have shown how to use MyExtensions. Now if you want either a global appsettings.json file or one per script, you can use the following extension:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    // needs: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.json, press F4 and add it as NUGET package
    public static IConfiguration AppSettings(string path = null)
    {
            IConfiguration config = null;
            var configFile = (path != null) ? path : Util.CurrentQueryPath.Replace(".linq", ".appsettings.json");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(configFile))
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(configFile);
                config = builder.Build();
            }
            else
            {
                configFile.Dump("Not found");
            }
            return config;
    }
}
```

You can also store it directly in your C# program, but this way it's available per default and you need to do the NUGET loading only once.

Say you have written a LinqPad program `"YourCSharpProgram.linq"`.
Now you can provide configuration like

```cs
var config1 = MyExtensions.AppSettings();
```

or like

```cs
var config2 = MyExtensions.AppSettings("C:\MyGlobalSettings\appsettings.json");
```

The first option, config1, will expect the the settings beneath the file `"YourCSharpProgram.linq"` and appends `"appsettings.json"` to it, meaning that your settings have to be in `"YourCSharpProgram.linq.appsettings.json"` in the same folder as the program.
The second option just uses the absolute path as specified.

If your settings file contains

```cs
{
    "AzureStorage": {
        "StorageConnectionString": "some connection string"
    }
}
```

you can access it like

```cs
var config = MyExtensions.AppSettings();
string connectionString = config.GetSection("AzureStorage").GetSection("StorageConnectionString").Value.ToString();
connectionString.Dump();
```

**NOTE:** A second way to use configuration is to place the absolute path of your JSON file in LinqPads F4 dialog. In LinqPad 5, that was better because there was a separate tab for the settings file (there it was `AppConfig`, because version 5 is for .NET, not for .NET core). You have to reference it just as you would do it with an assembly, and it's not obvious. So I prefer it as described above.

---

## .Dump() - revisited

### Extension for click action

Creating a button with a click action appearing on the Results tab in LinqPad is easy:

```cs
using LINQPad.Controls;
void Main()
{
    var btn = (new Button("Click me", (Button b) =>
    {
        // display message on click, then hide button
        "Button was clicked".Dump();
        b.Visible = false;
    })).Dump();
}
```

But sometimes it is useful if you can click a button to perform an action on a particular row - in other words, something which produces an output like this:

[image: Example for click column]

You can do this by writing an Extension (which you could store in "My Extensions" as described earlier - but you can also have an individual static extension class inside your LinqPad program).

Skeleton of the extension class:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{   
    // add here: ActionButton<TSource>
        
    // add here: DumpAction<T>

    // optional: DumpActionDict<K, V>
}
```

All of the static methods below **need to be inside of this static not nested extension class** (or in LinqPad's "My Extensions" as mentioned before).

The rest of the code goes directly into the `void Main() { ... }` method. **Note** that the project type must be **C# Program**.

First, we need to have an action button; to create one in a simple way we're using this helper method:

```cs
public static LINQPad.Controls.Button ActionButton<TSource>(this TSource arg, 
    string text, System.Action<TSource> selector)
    => new LINQPad.Controls.Button(text, 
       (LINQPad.Controls.Button b) => { selector(arg); });
```

The function takes a source type and allows to create a Button labled with a text and a selector (we'll see what that is in a minute).

With that, we can define a DumpAction method as follows:

```cs
public static void DumpAction<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lst, Action<T> selector,
                    string description = "", string clickText = "Click me")
{
    lst.Select(val => new
    {
        val, click = val.ActionButton<T>(clickText, selector)
    }).Dump(description);
}
```

This appends a column with buttons inside that you can click.
Then we need a DumpClick method

```cs
public static void DumpClick<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, string description="", string text = "")

{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) text.Dump(description);
    foreach (var element in data)
    {
        Util.OnDemand(element.ToString(), () => myFunc(element) ).Dump();
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) "--------".Dump();
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```cs
// list to display
var myList = new List<string>()
{
    "Apple", "Pie"
};
```

All you have to do is:

```cs
myList.DumpAction((x) => myAction(x), "Click Extension");
```

Which will do essentially the same as you know from .Dump() method.
Now all it takes is to define a method `myAction` that is being called:

```cs
void myAction(string payload)
{
    payload.Dump("myAction");
}
```

This method will be called if you click the button passing the string value of the list item to it.

**Note:** You can do the same for Dictionaries, and the extension above already works for them, but it is taking a lot of space
in the results window for each row - to solve that, you can define a second extension method:

```cs
public static void DumpActionDict<K, V>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> lst, 
                    Action<K> selector,
                    string description = "", string clickText = "Click me")
                    
{
    lst.Select(val => new
    {
        val.Key, val.Value, click = val.Key.ActionButton<K>(clickText, selector)
    }).Dump(description);
}
```

Use it like:

```cs
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    ["a"] = "x",
    ["b"] = "y"
};

myDict.DumpActionDict((x) => myAction(x), "Extension for dict");
```

**Note:** It is also possible to format the text inside the button differently, take a look at this example:

```cs
public static LINQPad.Controls.Button ActionButton<TSource>(this TSource arg, string text,
    System.Action<TSource> selector)
{
    var btn = new LINQPad.Controls.Button(onClick: (LINQPad.Controls.Button b) => { selector(arg); });
    btn.HtmlElement.InnerHtml = $"<small>{text}</small>";
    return btn;
}
```

That will make the button text smaller. You can use any HTML element(s).

---

### Coloring your dump with Util.HighlightIf

You can create colored dumps by using `Util.HighlightIf(condition, object)` or `Util.HighlightIf(condition, htmlcolor, object)`.

The following example, taken from LinqPad's release notes and colored it a bit more shows how:

```cs
void Main()
{
    (from file in new DirectoryInfo(Util.LINQPadFolder).GetFiles()
    select 
        Util.HighlightIf(file.Extension == ".txt", "lightblue",
        Util.HighlightIf(file.Extension == ".json" 
                                || file.Extension == ".xml", "lightcyan",
        Util.HighlightIf(file.Extension == ".cmd" 
                                || file.Extension == ".bat", "lightyellow",
        Util.HighlightIf(file.Extension == ".dll", "lightgreen",  
        Util.HighlightIf(file.Extension == ".exe", 
            new {file.Name, 
              Length=Util.HighlightIf(file.Length>999999,"orange",file.Length),
              LastWriteDate=DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
        )))))).Dump();
}
```

Now, what does it do?
It colors the cells based on

- file extension. The file extensions `.bat`,`.txt`, `.json`, `.cmd`, `.dll`, `.xml` and `.exe` have different colors for each of them (some share the same color).
- file size. If the size exceeds `999999 bytes`, its cell is colored in orange.

This will create a dump like:

[image: colordump]

---

### Updating a message inline

Sometimes it is useful to **overwrite the text** you dumped rather than putting it into a new line, for example if you're performing a long-running query and want to show its progress etc (see also ProgressBar below). This can be done by using a `DumpContainer`, you can use it as shown in the

**Example 1:**

```cs
void Main()
{
   var dc = new DumpContainer("Doing something ... ").Dump("Some Action");
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait 3 seconds
   dc.Content += "Done.";
}
```

[image: DumpContainerAnimation]

**Note** that for some more complex objects, you might have to use `dc.UpdateContent(obj);` rather than `dc.Content=...`.

**Example 2:**

```cs
void Main()
{
    var dc = new DumpContainer().Dump("Some Action");
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        dc.UpdateContent($"Countdown: {i}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
    };
    dc.UpdateContent("Ready for take off!");
}
```

---

### Showing progress - Util.ProgressBar

Showing the progress can also be done by using a ProgressBar as follows:

**Example:**

```cs
void Main()
{
    var prog = new Util.ProgressBar("Processing").Dump();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(50); prog.Percent = i;
    }
    prog.Caption = "Done";
}
```

This is similar to the dump example before, but this time showing a nice progress bar animation.

[image]

---

### JavaScript functions (using `.Dump()`)

Since version **5.42 beta** of LinqPad you can embed JavaScript functions and call them directly from your C# code. Although this has some limitations (compared with JSFiddle), it is a nice way to quickly test some JavaScript code in LinqPad.

**Example:**

```cs
void Main()
{
    // JavaScript inside C#
    var literal = new LINQPad.Controls.Literal("script",
    @"function jsFoo(x) { 
        alert('jsFoo got parameter: ' + x); 
        var a = ['x', 'y', 'z']; external.log('Fetched \'' + a.pop() + '\' from Stack');
        external.log('message from C#: \'' + x + '\''); 
    }"); 
    // render & invoke
    literal.Dump().HtmlElement.InvokeScript(true, "jsFoo", "testparam");
}
```

In this example, a function `jsFoo` with one parameter is prepared and stored in the variable `literal`. Then, it is rendered and called via `.Dump().HtmlElement.InvokeScript(...)`, passing the parameter `testparam`.

The JavaScript function uses `external.Log(...)` to output text in LinqPad's output windows, and `alert(...)` to display a popup message.

You can simplify this by adding the following **extension class/methods:**

```cs
public static class ScriptExtension
{
    public static object RunJavaScript(this LINQPad.Controls.Literal literal, 
                                       string jsFunction, params object[] p)
    {
        return literal.Dump().HtmlElement.InvokeScript(true, jsFunction, p);
    }
    
    public static LINQPad.Controls.Literal CreateJavaScript(string jsFunction)
    {
        return new LINQPad.Controls.Literal("script", jsFunction);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the previous example as follows:

```cs
    // JavaScript inside C#
    var literal = ScriptExtension.CreateJavaScript(
    @"function jsFoo(x) { 
        alert('jsFoo got parameter: ' + x); 
        var a = ['x', 'y', 'z']; external.log('Fetched \'' + a.pop() + '\' from Stack');
        external.log('message from C#: \'' + x + '\''); 
    }"); 

    // render & invoke
    literal.RunJavaScript("jsFoo", "testparam");
```

That has the same effect, but is easier to read (if you intend to do more JavaScript ;-) ).

Another option, if you like Lambda expressions and you don't like to specify the function name as string each time you're calling it, you can do:

```cs
var jsFoo = ScriptExtension.CreateJavaScript(
            @"function jsFoo(x) { ...  }"); 
ScriptExtension.RunJavaScript(() => jsFoo, "testparam");
```

provided you've added the helper function

```cs
public static object RunJavaScript(Expression<Func<LINQPad.Controls.Literal>> expr,  
                                   params object[] p)
{
    LINQPad.Controls.Literal exprValue = expr.Compile()();
    string jsFunction = ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;
    return exprValue.Dump().HtmlElement.InvokeScript(true, jsFunction, p);
}
```

to the class `ScriptExtension`. This will resolve the variable name you used (here `jsFoo`) which happens to be the same name as the JavaScript function itself (Note how the lambda expression is used to resolve the variable name, this cannot be done by using `nameof(paramName)` inside the function).

---

## xUnit - Unit testing with LinqPad

Did you know you can write unit tests in LinqPad? For example, you can use the xUnit framework. For version 5 of LinqPad, it is available through LinqPad's NUGET support - via <kbd>F4</kbd> - in the dialog click <kbd>Add NUGET....</kbd>. And since version 6 of LinqPad, it is built-in (Menu Query -> Add XUnit test support). Here's a step-by-step description how to
[use xUnit with LinqPad V5, V6 or V7.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61792306/1016343)

**Example 1:**

```cs
[Fact] void TestDb1()
{
    var ctx = this; // "this" represents the database context
    Assert.True(ctx.Categories.Any(), "No categories");
    string.Join(", ", ctx.Categories.Select(s => s.CategoryName).ToList()).Dump("Categories");
    Assert.True(ctx.Products.Any(), "No Products");
    string.Join(", ", ctx.Products.Select(s => s.ProductName).ToList()).Dump("Products");   
}
```

This example needs a [Northwind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases) sample database (set up as Linq to SQL or as Entity Framework Core Connection), assigned to the query, and XUnit Test support added (select Query -> Add XUnit test support in LinqPad). It will print all categories and products to the Results window. The test fails, if there are no categories or products in the database.

**Example 2:**

```cs
// for MemberData
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetNumbers()
{
    yield return new object[] { 5, 1, 3, 9 };  // 1st row: a, b, c, sum (succeeds)
    yield return new object[] { 7, 0, 5, 13 }; // 2nd row: a, b, c, sum (fails)
}

[Theory] 
[MemberData(nameof(GetNumbers))] // easier to handle than [ClassData(typeof(MyClass))]
void Test_Xunit(int a, int b, int c, int expectedSum) 
     => Assert.Equal (expectedSum, a + b + c);
```

This example uses a `[Theory]` with the member function `GetNumbers()` to fill in the parameters `a, b, c` and `expectedSum` and gives you more flexibility than a `[Fact]`. A `[Fact]` cannot have any parameters. The test fails if the expected sum is not equal to the sum of a+b+c. This is the case for the 2nd row: The assert will output: `(a: 7, b: 0, c: 5, expectedSum: 13)`.

**Note:** You can also use InlineData (e.g. `[InlineData(1,2,3,6)]`) multiple times for a theory passing the values directly, and you can even combine it with the MemberData attribute. It will add all values to the test and execute it.

---

## Multiple database support

The paid version of LinqPad (LinqPad 6 Premium) supports multiple databases in a query.

Below I am describing the steps for the database properies you get if you select "Linq to SQL (Optimized for SQL Server)".

Either create a new connection or open up an existing one. Open the **Database Properties**, select **one** database (**don't** use "Display all in a TreeView)

[image: database properties]

and then tick-mark "Include Additional Databases" - that will bring up another dialog where you can add multiple databases:

[image: additional databases]

Click <kbd>Pick from List...</kbd> and you can choose + select another database. When you are done, click <kbd>Close</kbd> to close the additional dialog and then <kbd>Ok</kbd> to close the database properties.

Databases selected there are "secondary" contexts (listed with the database name in "this" UserQuery), the first database (which you selected under "Specify new or existing database") is a "primary" context (which means, the tables appear directly in "this" UserQuery).

In the connections window, this will be shown as

> ".\MyInstance\AdventureWorks2017 + AdventureWorks2017 + Northwind"

---

In the code below I am using "AdventureWorks2017" as **primary context** and "AdventureWorks2017" and "Northwind" as **secondary contexts.**

Prepared like this, you can do:

```cs
public UserQuery ctx => this; // context
void Main()
{
 // "primary database"
 ctx.Products.Select(s => new {s.ProductID, Name=s.Name}).Take(3).Dump("AdventureWorks");

 // "secondary" databases
 var aw = ctx.AdventureWorks2017;
 var nw = ctx.Northwind;

 nw.Products.Select(s => new {s.ProductID, Name=s.ProductName}).Take(3).Dump("Northwind");
 aw.Products.Select(s => new {s.ProductID, Name=s.Name}).Take(3).Dump("AdventureWorks");
}
```

Both sample databases used in this example are from Microsoft, can be downloaded free, and they both have a `Products` table, but with different properties / fields: You can see that I've renamed the ProductName / Name so it appears in all queries as Name.

The program will give you the result:

[image: result]

Download links:
[AdventureWorks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms), [Northwind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases), [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

---

Comment: Listtable only work in Linkpad 5, not 6&7

Comment: @Thomas Adrian - Thanks for the hint,  I will try to find a way/workaround for newer Linqpad > V5 and will get back to you once I found it.

Comment: https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/comment/6549#Comment_6549

Comment: @Thomas Adrian - so you found it in the LinqPad forum. Thanks for providing the link! I cite from the forum:  You need to press F4 for query properties and tick "Reference LINQ-to-SQL assemblies".

Comment: Added the hint to the answer text.

Answer (score 2):

Dump is a global extension method and SubmitChanges comes from the DataContext object which is a System.Data.Linq.DataContext object.

LP adds only Dump and Disassemble as far as I'm aware. Though I would highly recommend opening it in Reflector to see what else is there that can be used. One of the more interesting things is the LINQPad.Util namespace which has some goodies used by LINQPad internally.

Comment: **Note:** In newer versions of LinqPad: Click on `.Dump()` or any other method in the source editor, press **F12**  to "reflect". This is now built into the tool!