# KeePass API to Access Currently Open Database from Code

Tags: c#, api, security, sdk, keepass

I am currently using the available SDK in C# to access a KeePass database file. The problem is there is not much information on the API from what I can find and I want to be able to **read the currently open database** just like the plugin for Remote Desktop Manager does as shown below.

[image: Remote Desktop Manager KeePass integration]

This thread sort of helps to initialize a connection and get the entries: [Store sensitive information inside keepass database from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680352/store-sensitive-information-inside-keepass-database-from-c-sharp) but I am looking to detect a currently open database and access it from memory if it is available. I know it's possible because the Remote Desktop Manager software is able to do it. I didn't have to specify a password or anything. I just had my KeePass workspace unlocked and it was able to detect it and let me make selections from it.