# Get a password from KeePass

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, keepass

I want to hide a server password when I make the connection in my code with .net. The password is in KeePass but I don't know how to get it.

This is my connection code to the server:

```
ftpConnection = new FTPConnection();
ftpConnection.ServerAddress = "0000"; // here i want to hide it 
ftpConnection.UserName = "****";
ftpConnection.Password = "*****";
ftpConnection.TransferType = FTPTransferType.BINARY;   

try
{
     ftpConnection.Connect();
     ftpConnection.GetWorkingDirectory();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{   
     fileDetails = ftpConnection.GetFileInfos();
     //string[] nomsFichier = ftpConnection.GetFiles();
     MessageBox.Show("Vous etes connecté au serveur!");
}
```

If any one can help me I'll be so thankful !!!

Comment: There are several plug-ins for KeePass covering KeePass integration scenarios. Whether some of thus plug-ins are a very good and easy fit for your particular needs, i don't know. The only thing i can suggest: Do your research, look at the [integration plug-ins offered on KeePass' web site](https://keepass.info/plugins.html) and see which might be suitable for your needs. If push comes to shove, and you were find none of those integration plug-ins to be suitable, i am afraid you would have to write your own plug-in (some plug-ins might be available as source, allowing you to learn from them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store sensitive information inside keepass database from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680352/store-sensitive-information-inside-keepass-database-from-c-sharp)