# CS1061 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: x>>' does not contain a definition for dump

Tags: c#, linq, keepass

I just want to get the password out of my software KeePass.

After using the code from an old question here [Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680352/store-sensitive-information-inside-keepass-database-from-c-sharp), im getting this error message:

`S1061  'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Group, string Title, string Username, string Password>>' does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no accessible extension method 'Dump' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Group, string Title, string Username, string Password>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  KeePasso    C:\Users\prusinma\source\repos\KeePasso\KeePasso\Program.cs 36  Active`

This is the code im using:

```
using System.Linq;
using KeePassLib;
using KeePassLib.Keys;
using KeePassLib.Serialization;

namespace KeePasso
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var dbpath = @"\\xxx\Home_VIE\xxx\Desktop\KeePassDatabase\Database.kdbx";
            var keypath = @"\\xxx\Home_VIE\xxx\Desktop\KeePassDatabase\Database.key";
            var masterpw = "1234abcd";

            var ioConnInfo = new IOConnectionInfo { Path = dbpath };
            var compKey = new CompositeKey();
            compKey.AddUserKey(new KcpPassword(masterpw));
            compKey.AddUserKey(new KcpKeyFile(IOConnectionInfo.FromPath(keypath))); // Keyfile

            var db = new PwDatabase();
            db.Open(ioConnInfo, compKey, null);

            var kpdata = from entry in db.RootGroup.GetEntries(true)
                         select new
                         {
                             Group = entry.ParentGroup.Name,
                             Title = entry.Strings.ReadSafe("Title"),
                             Username = entry.Strings.ReadSafe("UserName"),
                             Password = entry.Strings.ReadSafe("Password"),
                         };

            kpdata.Dump(); // this is how Linqpad outputs stuff
            db.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In the last rows in the code, there is a red underline at `Dump`. Which displays the same error message i shared above.

I was already trying to find similiar questions and in most of them they were related to the type. But as i can see, all the datas/entries in Title, Username and Password are strings.

Would appreciate if someone could help me here out. Id also be open for a other solution how to read out the password from the database.

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear - are you actually trying to run this code in Linqpad? As the comment indicates, that line is using Linqpad functionality.

Comment: The clear hint here is `this is how Linqpad outputs stuff`.

Comment: https://www.linqpad.net

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699466/how-do-i-use-the-linqpad-dump-extension-method-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks ill have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `kpdata` is collection of anonimous types, which has overriden `ToString` (and if `entry.Strings.ReadSafe` returns `string` or some type with "correctly" overriden `ToString` method) you can just use `Console.WriteLine` on it:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, kpdata));; // instead of kpdata.Dump();
```

Otherwise you will need [to find a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699466/how-do-i-use-the-linqpad-dump-extension-method-in-visual-studio) to import LINQPad's `Dump` method into your project or just use some json serialization library to convert object to string.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to simply output the entries with WriteLine. But my Output doesnt look correct `System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[KeePassLib.PwEntry,<>f__AnonymousType0`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]`

Comment: @Beardy, sorry, missed that it is collection. Than you can use something like `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, kpdata));`

Comment: Oh wow. It actually worked!!! I was never expecting someone giving a solution that fast! Can you give me maybe an example, how to get only the password and store it in a variable?

Comment: @Beardy - you have a collection so theoretically there can be multiple passwords - in this case which one of them do you need?

Comment: The collection/database has 3 rows called Title, Username and Password.
Lets say the Titles name is Azkaban. Then i want to get the password from Title Azkaban and store it in a variable

Comment: @Beardy I would recommend to get familiar with [LINQ](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/linq/linq-query-syntax-vs-method-syntax/). Something like `kpdata.Where(d => d.Title == ....).FirstOrDefault()?.Password` should do the trick.

Comment: Was hoping to skip that LINQ part haha. But ill have a look! Thanks so so so so much for your help =)

Comment: `var pw = kpdata.Where(d => d.Title == "Azkaban").FirstOrDefault()?.Password;` and then `Console.WriteLine(pw.ToString());` works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to object!

```
//But This works!
((object)d).Dump();

// as does this)
(d as Object).Dump()
```