# Capture output of LINQPad

Tags: linqpad

Is there a way to capture the content of the results panel in LINQPad; that is to say, capture it programatically and e.g. save it to a file?

Comment: What's your scenario? Presumably you're aware that the output is HTML?

Comment: I am running a bunch of tests and would like to dump the test results to (X)HTML files. It's not a huge deal though, as I could just create an interceptor function, e.g. Dump2 which delegates to Dump, as well as outputting to a file. Still, it'd be a nice addition to LINQPad.

Answer (score 1):

Check out LINQPad's extension methods. Here's a good Stack Overflow question on it:

[LINQPad [extension] methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555317/linqpad-extension-methods)