# LinqPad Tutorial

Tags: linqpad

Hi I am looking forward to learn Linqpad. Can anybody tell me if there is any e-book or tutorial site that can help me learn Linqpad Step by Step from the starting. I tried searching it on the net, but was not able to find any good material. Please help as it ws really important for me.

Comment: If you're looking for hidden features of LinqPad, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006038/1016343) out.

Answer (score 24):

When you start linqpad there is a samples tab in the lower left. The "LINQPad 5 minute introduction" is a real simple interactive introduction to linqpad. That should give a pretty good overview of linqpad features if you already know you way around c#.

11/10/2017 - Version 5.25 made it even easier. The application is bundled with more tutorial/introduction stuff. You can find it by going to "Help | Tutorial and Reference".

Answer (score 10):

The samples are a great place to start.
I also created 2 introductory videos for Linqpad.
http://dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2013/01/15/developer-tools-screencast-linqpad-part-1/
http://dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2013/01/23/developer-tools-screencast-linqpad-part-2/

Answer (score 3):

There's a few videos [here](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/LinqPad) that give an overview to [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

LinqPad is only a tool - and an quite an easy one to use at that - just run the exe and start coding. If you are after help with LINQ in C# or VB, then LinqPad has build in tutorials for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gradually building up linqpad tutorials on my developer tips blog, I've started of with: [reading CSV in linqpad](http://www.developertipoftheday.com/2012/10/read-csv-in-linqpad.html).

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this post as your first, but perhaps in a mix of tutorials that you are reading. This is a nice way of learning how "my extensions" work in the real life situation of parsing CSV - which I haven't seen many tutorials cover (hence why I decided to investigate it further).

Comment: Reading your blog gave me an idea to add an extension method for converting UTC time to local time. Thanks!