# LINQPad namespace documentation

Tags: linqpad

Where can I read the documentation for the types in the `LINQPad` namespace? I tried pressing F1 for help, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important type is `LINQPad.Util`, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555317/linqpad-extension-methods).

Also, `LINQPad.PanelManager` is useful for displaying WPF & Windows Forms controls (it gives you more flexiblity than you get just by dumping the control). See Help | What's New for an explanation on how this works.

Some of the other types exist for [extensibility](http://www.linqpad.net/extensibility.aspx).