# Why cant I use the {0} when writing in MsgBox?

Tags: c#

If I want to show something in a `console` I usually write it like this: `Console.Write("Hello{0}", AnyNumber);`.

But if I use `Interaction.MsgBox` and write `Interaction.MsgBox("Hello {0}, AnyNumber");` I am getting an error, why is that?

I like to use placeholders like `{0}` a lot more than `+` (string concatenation) when writing, I think it is easier to write it like that...

So my question is: Why can't I use placeholders in MsgBox and is there any other way to use them?

Here is a example how I would like to use it in MsgBox:

```
static void multiplikation(int tal1, int tal2)
{        
    if (tal1*tal2 == 100)
    {
          Interaction.MsgBox("Hello!\nResult:\n" + (tal1 * tal2));
    }
    else
    {
          Interaction.MsgBox("Resultat:\n" + (tal1 * tal2));
    }
}
static void addition(int tal1, int tal2)
{
    if (tal1 + tal2 == 100)
    {
         Console.Write("Hello!\nResult:{0}\n", (tal1 + tal2));
    }
    else
    {
         Console.Write("Resultat:{0}\n", (tal1 + tal2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use String.Format("Hello {0}", "user");

Comment: Use String.Format http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As @MichaelB says or add your own extension method, say MsgBoxf that uses string.Format

Comment: @Kenny: I have provided such a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22557566/1016343).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Interaction.MsgBox` receives a string as its first parameter. If you want to format a string, you have to do that yourself, and pass the formatted string to `Interaction.MsgBox`:

```
Interaction.MsgBox(string.Format("Hello!\nResult:{0}\n", (tal1 + tal2)));
```

On the other hand, `Console.Write` was written with overloads that allow the formatting to be performed inside `Console.Write`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that unlike `Console.Write`, `Interaction.Msgbox` does not know anything about `string.Format`: It just displays the string "as is".

---

Since **C# version 6**, there is a comfortable way:

```
 Interaction.MsgBox($"Result:\n {tal1 * tal2}");
```

The '$' is telling the compiler to treat `{tal1 * tal2}` as an expression and insert the result into the string. More details about this so-called string interpolation:

> With string interpolation, *expressions* within curly braces `{}` can
>   also be evaluated. The result will be inserted at the corresponding
>   location within the string. For example, to calculate the maximum of
>   `foo` and `bar` and insert it, use `Math.Max` within the curly
>   braces:
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine($"And the greater one is: {
> Math.Max(foo, bar) }");
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> And the greater one is: 42
>
> *Note: Any leading or trailing whitespace (including space, tab and CRLF/newline) between the curly brace and the expression is completely ignored and not included in the output*

---

For **all C# versions** (especially the ones before C#6) you can do the following:

Instead of having to invoke `string.Format` every time, you can create a function like

```
    public Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult MsgBox(string msg, params object[] p)
    {
        var fmt = string.Format(msg, p);
        var msgStyle = Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly;
        return Interaction.MsgBox(fmt, msgStyle, "Information");
    }
```

This can be used as follows:

```
    var tal1=1; var tal2=2;
    MsgBox("Hello!\nResult:{0}\n", (tal1 + tal2));
```

**Note:** This solution supports not only `{0}`, but also `{1}, {2}, ...` because I have used a params array. Hence, the following is working too:

```
MsgBox("Calculation: {0} + {1} = {2}", tal1, tal2, (tal1+tal2));
```

which outputs `Calculation: 1 + 2 = 3`.

You can read [here (at Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.msgbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) more about the `Interaction.MsgBox` method, how to change the style of the messagebox (e.g. how to display Yes/No/Cancel buttons and about the `MsgBoxResult` values being returned) so you can tailor it to your needs.

---

This is the complete program, you can run it in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) or Visual Studio:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            var tal1=1; var tal2=2;
            MsgBox("Hello!\nResult:{0}\n", (tal1 + tal2));
            MsgBox("Calculation: {0} + {1} = {2}", tal1, tal2, (tal1+tal2));
    }

    public static MsgBoxResult MsgBox(string msg, params object[] p)
    {
        var fmt=string.Format(msg, p);
        var msgStyle= Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly;
        return Interaction.MsgBox(fmt, msgStyle, "Information");
    }
```

---

Don't forget to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`, using the namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in order to run this example.

If you're using LinqPad, right-click, choose "Query properties..." then add the dll in "Additional references" and the namespace in "Additional Namespace imports".

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine` has an overloads which supports a `string.Format` type implementation.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As pointed out in the comments, you will need to use `string.Format()` to replicate that behavior for `Interaction.MsgBox`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the string format method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx