# Convert decimal value to custom format

Tags: c#, decimal

```
Decimal money = 7;

var result=money.Tostring("C);
```

result displays $7.00

How can i show result as **"7.00"**( with 2 numerics after point) without currency symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`"C"` Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) is for currency representation of numbers. It uses your `CurrentCulture`'s [`CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CurrencyDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties as a result. (If you don't use `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter, of course..)

You can use `N2` format insead. Like;

```
decimal money = 7;
money.ToString("N2").Dump(); //7.00
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(money.ToString("N2"));
```

Read:

- [`"N"` Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString)

> **Result: Integral and decimal digits**, group separators, **and a decimal
>   separator** with optional negative sign.
>
> Supported by: All numeric types.
>
> **Precision specifier: Desired number of decimal places.**

Comment: What is `Dump()`? I did not find an MSDN reference on it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: @Neolisk Sorry, I should mentioned it. `.Dump()` is an extension method of [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555317/linqpad-extension-methods

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = money.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard format can do this:

```
var result = money.Tostring("N2");
```

Reference:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Look under `"N" or "n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var result = money.ToString("f");
```

Comment: what is result with f ?

Comment: @user3713890, I want you to try :)

Comment: Check here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `N2` in `ToString` like

```
var result=money.Tostring("N2");
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has documented the possible ways to format a decimal [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
"G", "F", "N", "G2", "F2", "N2", "0.00", and others would all accomplish your task.
I would check them out and see which one is right for you.