# LinqPad4 does not show results

Tags: sql, linq

I am playing around with LinqPad4. This is my SQL Statement that returns 2 records, my equivalent Linq statement executed successfully, however it does not show any results.

```
select top 2 * from Nums


var testing = (from nums in Nums select new {nums.N}).Take(50);
```

[image]

[image]

Why??

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned the result of the query to the variable `testing`.  If you want to see the contents in the results pane, you can dump it like this.

```
testing.Dump();
```

You could also switch the language to C# expression, and ditch the variable declaration entirely.

Answer (score 1):

`Dump()` outputs your result to the output window.

So it is either:

```
var testing = (from nums in Nums select new {nums.N}).Take(50).Dump();
// or
testing.Dump();
```

Joe Albahari (the author of LinqPad) has also written an article about both output methods `Dump()` and `Dissamble()` here: [LINQPad [extension] methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555317/linqpad-extension-methods).