# Formatting date to specific format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

What is the best way to format a string date to a specific format?

For example if input was `30/09/2014` it would be formatted as `2014-09-30` or any other similar date format for the former?

Comment: Do a .ToString() on the DateTime object and specify the format you like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx. however if you are already looking at a string date then you should convert it to a datetime object and then get the string format to your liking

Comment: It's not really clear what you've tried so far, or whether you're looking for parsing as well as formatting advice. Calling `DateTime.ToString` with a custom format string is probably want you want here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, `DateTime` doesn't have *any* implicit format. Strings have.

Sounds like you just need to parse your string and format it with [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "30/09/2014";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();
    // Result will be 2014-09-30
}
```

Since I create this example on [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), [`.Dump()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555317/linqpad-extension-methods) is just an extension method.

Just be careful when you parse a string that have `/` as a date separator.  [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with the current culture of specified culture date separator*. That means, your `CurrentCulture` or specified culture's [`DateSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is not `/`, your parsing operation will fail *even* if your string and format are the same format.

That's why I used [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in my example since it has `/` as a `DateSeparator`.

Comment: I assume that you used linqpad? maybe remove the `.Dump()`

Comment: @DavidPilkington Yes, I mentioned it in my answer. Just first line under the example.