# Converting a DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two string variables.  The first one is from a label (This date will be subject to changed dependant on a datetimepicker). The second one is a time that is selected in a combo box.  The format is in this example -

```
lblActualDate.Text - 11 June 2015
comboStartTime.Text - 12.00AM
```

I am getting errors about the strings not being in the correct format to convert to date time.

My aim is to make an instance with the values from a form
Here is my code -

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dateString = lblActualDate.Text + " " + comboStartTime.SelectedItem;

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd MMMM yyyy hh.mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        int length = int.Parse(comboLength.SelectedText);
        string description = txtBoxSubject.Text;
        string location = txtBoxLocation.Text;

        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(startTime, length, description, location);
        Appointments appointments = new Appointments();

        appointments.Add(newAppointment);
        appointments.Save();

        txtBoxLocation.Clear();
        txtBoxSubject.Clear();
        Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Consider using [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You need to convert the string variables into a DateTime type

Comment: take a look at [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Aside from already existing and correct answer, remember to add a whitespace between your strings when adding them OR properly change your custom date/time format if you're using one.

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses [standard date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That means your string format doesn't match one of these formats.

You can use [custom date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse your string like;

```
string s = "11 June 201512.00AM";
DateTime startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd MMMM yyyyhh.mmtt", 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also consider to put a white space between your date and time part.

Comment: Thnak you.  Do I need a namespace to use 'Dump()'.  It is showing an error

Comment: @Pete [`Dump`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555317/linqpad-extension-methods) is an extension method for [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). You definitly **don't** need to use it. Sorry about the confusion. Deleted that part. Generally, I use this tool for Stack Overflow questions to generate code examples.

Comment: I am a little confused as I am not writing to a console.  I need to store the date and time in a DateTime variable

Comment: Does there not need need to be any code in the brackets?

Comment: It isn't working i'm afraid.  "No overload for method takes 3 arguments -

Comment: string dateString = lblActualDate.Text + " " + comboStartTime.SelectedText;

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd mmmm yyyy hh.mmtt",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @Pete Sorry, it should be `ParseExact` not `TryParseExact`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time but unfortunately I still get an exception thrown.  There must be an error somewhere else in the code

Comment: @Pete Maybe. You can debug your code and see exact line throws any exception.

Comment: Yes. It was that line actually.   Am I using the correct code to get the combobox string?

Comment: It is still saying it is not the correct format.  There variables in the debug say this -
dateString  -  "11 June 2015 05.00AM"
startTime - {11/06/2015 5:00:00 AM}

Comment: @Pete If your hour part has leading zero for single digit, use `hh` specifier instead.

Comment: @Pete Oh yes, it is. I think you need a white space between `yyyy` and `hh` part since you want to parse as `...2015 05...`.

Comment: string dateString = lblActualDate.Text + " " + comboStartTime.SelectedItem;



            DateTime startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd Mmmm yyyy hh.mmTT", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  here is my code.  I added the white space earlier but still get the exception unfortunatly

Comment: @Pete Look at your format and mine. Are they equal? You should use `"dd MMMM yyyy hh.mmtt"` format.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've got some combinations with one digit, and others with two digits in either the **day** or **hour** portions of your date/time.

You can allow all the possibilities by building up an array of allowable formats and passing that to ParseExact:

```
string[] formats = { "d MMMM yyyy h.mmtt", "d MMMM yyyy hh.mmtt", "dd MMMM yyyy h.mmtt", "dd MMMM yyyy hh.mmtt" };
DateTime startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works now.
I have a problem on the next line --- int length = int.Parse(comboLength.SelectedItem);   Select item should be a string number ie,  270.  I would have thought this would be straight forward but apparently not

Comment: Perhaps there is nothing selected?...or you've got a value in the combo that is not actually an integer.  Wrap the `Parse` call in a Try/Catch block, or switch to `TryParse`.  Either way, figure out what value(s) are causing the errors and adjust accordingly...