# LINQPad access multiple databases in single file

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm using LINQPad, and am trying to make the following scenario work.

I've got a SQL server connection, and an Oracle connection. I need to query from both contexts within the same LINQPad file. I do NOT need cross-db capabilities (server side joins, etc) akin to what is addressed in ([LINQPad, using multiple datacontexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495357/linqpad-using-multiple-datacontexts)), but I do need to be able to access each independently. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this at present is to build the additional typed data context(s) in Visual Studio, and then reference the output assemblies from LINQPad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joe.  Do you have any plans to support this in the future, or will your suggestion be the way to do it for the foreseeable future?

Comment: There are no plans at present.