# Linqpad access tables from 2 databases in a single query

Tags: linq-to-sql, linqpad

In Linqpad how can I query against two databases on one query.

I have managed to add the 2 databases like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4928921/66975

so the connection says "db1 + db2".

However I am unsure how to access the tables from db2 to make queries.

I can query against tables in the first db. 
Note: both dbs contain more or less the same table names.

Comment: Did you try dragging a table from each database to the query box to see how it refers to them?

Comment: @sgmoore That did the trick, so <TableName> works for first db  and <DBName>.<TableName> works for the second db...Really feel as though I tried that before. Must have had a typo.